# How to stop excluded category from showing its sticky posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a loop with excluded category (Featured) so now my category is **not visible** inside the loop. 
Now here is my problem if I set my post inside **Featured category** to be "sticky" that post will **still show up** inside my loop. 
What I would like to accomplish is to ***hide that category sticky posts (Featured)***, but allow  my other posts (From other categories) to be "sticky".

My Loop:

```
<?php 
    $category = get_cat_ID('Featured');//Get our Featured Category     
    $args = array(           
    'category__not_in' => $category //Category is excluded 
                                   // but 'sticky' ones from Featured category
                                  // are still showing up...         
);

$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

if($wp_query->have_posts()):?><?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>

    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <div class="entry"> 

            <?php the_content(__('Read more','my-domain')); ?>  

        </div><!--/entry-->
    </div><!--/post_class-->        
    <?php endwhile; ?>  
    <?php endif; ?><!--END if THE LOOP-->
<?php
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Any thoughts how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a test system available, but according to [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), something like this should work:

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array(
    'category__not_in' => $category,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'post__not_in' => $sticky
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not work as expected because now it hides all my sticky posts, including the sticky posts from other categories...

Comment: Damn, sorry.  Can't see an obvious way to do it in one query then.  Can you do a query to get all sticky posts in your category, then just use those posts in the `post__not_in` clause?  I'm assuming the `ignore_sticky_posts` argument by itself doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `in_category()` in your loop, and do a `continue` if necessary.  My gut feeling is that would be less efficient though - I assume it'd mean more database calls.

Comment: I seems to be working as expected, after I removed 'post__not_in' => $sticky from your code.

Comment: Same problem here, but the directive `'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1` ( without `post__not_in` ) makes my code work.